# Android copy file APK to real device through tftp ( use Window)

Tags: android, file-transfer, tftp

My task is copy file apk to my device, and install it. this device only have board and screen. Can not copy file to this device like tranfer file through USB .

I think may be some one have done it already. Please teach me how to solve it.

Ah, I am using Window 7, not  Ubuntu >.<

Comment: what type of connetivity is avaiable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your device includes a running a TFTP server then you just need a TFTP client .
See i.e. Serva http://vercot.com/~serva/default.html (I'm related to Serva development)